# Xcode 7 ViewController Positioning Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I made a math application that uses formulae to solve specific problems e.g. area of a triangle. I originally fit all my content onto ViewControllers that were landscape orientation with an iPhone 4 inch size. It is designed so that you change ViewControllers to solve different types of problems e.g. one is area of triangle, one is cone surface area, with a ViewController used as a menu with buttons linked to all the other ones. I then wanted to size all my content to fit all screen sizes. Instead of changing the size of the content, I just decided to put it all in the center of the screen (I don't think there's an easier way. I put all the buttons in a button outlet collection, all the labels in a label outlet collection etc. Then I run through them with a for loop, setting their positions using the following code:

```
func Position() {
    print("Repositioning")
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let height = bounds.size.height
    if images != nil {
        for var x in images {
            x.center.y += (height-360)/2
            x.center.x += (width-568)/2
        }
    }
    else {
        print("not valid")
    }
    if buttons != nil {
        for var z in buttons {
            z.center.y += (height-360)/2
            z.center.x += (width-568)/2
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried to put this in ViewDidLoad() and it didn't work, even though it does not print "not valid". I don't understand why this is. I am using swift in Xcode7. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is to vague, what do you mean by "didn't work"? How is it different than when it does work

Comment: When I ran it on ios simulator with a larger size e.g. iPhone 6 plus, the content was not centered - there was no change. The app functions fine, but it is the size of an iPhone 5/5s on an iPhone 6 plus screen so it appears in the top left hand corner instead of being centered. Hopefully this clears it up, sorry :) @Jay

Comment: Why are you hard coding 360 and 568? Get rid of those and the center of your views should not be in the center of your screen.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't want everything in the center of the screen, I want everything in the view (there are multiple objects), to be centered as a whole, not each thing centered, otherwise they would be on top of each other. Sorry for the confusion @Jay

Comment: Ok, why not use contraints? Or simply center the superview to all these items if you don't want to use contraints? Just set the center of self.view(assuming this is your superview for these items) to width/2 , height/2

Comment: So do I type self.view = (width/2, height/2) in my view did load and it will work? It doesn't work so I know I'm missing something. What exactly do I type. Sorry for, I'm a beginner :) @Jay

Comment: If it's working the way I'm imagining from the post, you would add that line after 
let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let height = bounds.size.height

If you can share your project I can help.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get the error "Cannot assign a value of type '(Float,Float)' to a value of type'UIView!'" @Jay

Comment: Sorry, the code I posted was not meant to be copied. What I meant to say is set self.view 's center to the width/2 for its x and the height/2 for its y. I'm on mobile so I don't really want to write code but it would be self.view.center.x = width/2 and similar for height

Comment: I put this code in the ViewDidLoad function and I get no change in the placement of objects on a bigger screen(it doesn't center but I also don't get an error) ' self.view.center.x = (height/2)
        self.view.center.y = (width/2) ' Its on two lines @Jay